# Target word using jQuery and add style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, this could be a simple question, but my jQuery skills are just not quite up there (yet). I'm trying to target a specific word on a web page and add a style to it. The word I'm trying to target appears multiple times on the page. I googled around some and found this:

```
<script>
    var divContent = document.getElementById("styled").innerHTML;
    divContent = divContent.replace("Bevestigd","<span class='styled'>Bevestigd</span>");
    divContent = divContent.replace("Geannuleerd","<span class='styled-r'>Geannuleerd</span>");
    divContent = divContent.replace("Pending","<span class='styled-p'>Pending</span>");
    document.getElementById("styled").innerHTML = divContent;
</script>
```

This works, kind of... It only targets the first time it encounters the word and doesn't repeat it self. I found numerous pieces of code to target a word on a page but this one seems to work the best... Is there any one that could help me out?

Is there a `foreach` function I'm missing?

I also tried this code:

```
$('body').html(
    function(i,h){
        return h.replace(/(Nike)/g,'<span class="nike tm">$1</span>');
    });​
```

which seems a bit simpler but that didn't work... Maybe someone has a snippet for this or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your js code done on jquery. Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1c85vvt1/)

```
$('#styled').html(function(i,v){    
       v=v.replace(/Bevestigd/g,'<span class="styled">Bevestigd</span>');
       v=v.replace(/Geannuleerd/g,'<span class="styled-r">Geannuleerd</span>');
       v=v.replace(/Pending/g,'<span class="styled-p">Pending</span>');
       return v;
    });
```

This is done with regex. 
We can extend it further.

eg. To make the search case insensitive use `/Bevestigd/gi` instead of `/Bevestigd/g`.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Why does this code work and the other one not? Could you give some explanation?

Comment: The first bit of code checks only the first occurrence. In the answer I provided, I gave the word as a regex and a `g` which is a global search. So it'll replace all the occurrence.

Comment: Hope this answer helped. If yes, kindly upvote the answer.